# Clean install Spree 1.1.1 goes fine, not so for Spree 1.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I use the following steps to install Spree version 1.1.1,

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p318@my_spree_shop --create
gem install rails -v 3.2.3 --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem install spree -v 1.1.1 --no-ri --no-rdoc
rails new my_spree_shop -d postgresql
cd my_spree_shop
open config/database.yml # modify database settings
rake db:create
spree install # 'Enter'ing all defaults
```

This works, but the admin pages suggest to have version **1.1.2** because of a security vulnerability. Doing the same steps for spree **1.1.2** with Rails **3.2.6**, will result in the following error at the last step:

```
precompiling  assets
/Users/~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby /Users/~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-    p318@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'admin/spree_auth'
  (in /Users/~/Development/spree_pixelhobby/app/assets/javascripts/admin/all.js:9)
```

What should be done differently for Spree **1.1.2** ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because the wrong version of Spree is being installed when you run `bundle install`.

Specify the correct dependency in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'spree', '1.1.2'
```

And then run `bundle install` again.

Comment: Everytime I run 'spree install', it add 'gem 'spree' to the Gemfile. Which gives an error about specifying the gem twice with different version requirments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have to add `gem 'spree', '1.1.2'` to your Gemfile, but you have to remove it also after the `bundle update`, or you will get some other issues, later during `spree install`.

All steps for a clean install for Spree 1.1.2 & Rails 3.2.6

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p318@my_spree_shop --create
gem install rails -v 3.2.6 --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem install spree -v 1.1.2 --no-ri --no-rdoc
rails new my_spree_shop -d postgresql
cd my_spree_shop
```

Addition compared to installing Spree 1.1.1

```
echo "gem 'spree', '1.1.2'" >> Gemfile  # adding spree to the Gemfile
bundle update
sed -ie '$d' Gemfile # removing the line you just added.
```

edit your db configurations and create the databases

```
vi config/database.yml
rake db:create
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

And finaly:

```
spree install
```